# Waiting for modal dialog to close before execution code in Java

Tags: java, swing, modal-dialog, jdialog

I'm using Java, Swing in NetBeans and I have there main JFrame and some JDialog window.

I click on a button and JDialog is created, but all code that is after opening this JDialog is instantly executed. But I want it to execute when the JDialog is closed (JDialog is modal and it blocks main frame but not its code).

Example:

```
private void buttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)    
{                                       
    button.setText("Starting");
    About.main(null);
    button.setText("Ending");
}
```

And now: After clicking button it opens JDialog and text on the button is "ending".

But I want: To click the button, it should has text "starting", then JDialog should appear and, but now, after it is closed the "ending" should be the caption.

How to do it?

Comment: What is `About.main(null)`??

Comment: Well, when I create JDialog using NetBeans it automatically generate a class and essential code. It also generates a static function "main" which actually creates a object of class "About".

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: But it's hard to post a short code of it. Do you want me to paste here the whole class "About" - it is just nothing more than what is generated by NetBeans.

I just want to open some modal dialog which will prevent next code from executing. For example in Delphi modal windows have this ability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said that you are using netbeans, when main method it's generated wraps object creation with [SwingUtilities#invokeLater](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) that means this code will happen after all pending AWT events have been processed. So as your `System.out.println("end")` is in an event your another event will execute after previous event finish!, that's why you see in console prints "end".

I don't know if it's a good design using another main method rather than your main method for whole application like a normal method.

IMO i just would use, or making an own "builder" method, cause with netbeans generation also set L&F again.

So for solving your issue just use or make your own builder method without wrapping it with `invokeLater`.

```
new MyDialog(null,true).setVisible(Boolean.TRUE); //may be not null 1st arg and a Frame or use SwingUtilities.windowForThisComponent(mycomponent);
```

Comment: Thx, it works. 

You just have to remover "invokeLater" and use "main" method, as I did.

Or write 

    About x = new About(this,true);
    x.setVisible(true);

Comment: @user3144058 Yep, i wouldn't use main method cause the main method is the entry point for an application, and you are not using like that..